# CALL METHOD and method chaining

Tags: abap

For CALL METHOD - Static Method Call (Obsolete), the ABAP keyword documentation says: "If CALL METHOD is used for the standalone method call, no chained method calls are possible ..."

Nevertheless, the following happily executes on an 7.40 system. Isn't that an example of a standalone method call? Or else, what am I getting wrong?

```
REPORT ZUTEST3.

CLASS class_parent Definition.
   PUBLIC Section.
   METHODS m1 returning value(r) type ref to class_parent.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS class_parent Implementation. 
   Method m1.
       create object r.
       write / 'm1'.
   EndMethod.
ENDCLASS.

start-of-selection.
data cl type ref to class_parent.
CREATE OBJECT cl.
CALL METHOD cl->m1( )->m1( ).
```

Edit: Disclaimer

We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. In particular, we have no intention to write new ABAP code. But instead, our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements and obscure syntax variants. Furthermore, I'd like to mention that I'm not an ABAP expert.

Comment: can you add the link to the documentation please?

Comment: On a different note: why not set up a tiny NetWeaver and let ABAP’s own parser do the parsing? Expose the parser as a REST service and connect Java to it.

Comment: @Florian. An appealing idea, but not viable for us. Our tool is quite old, predating the mentioned capability. So using it would mean to rewrite the tool completely. Our tool can run locally without connection to an SAP system. And, of course, we do much more than parsing and hence need control on how the parse tree looks like exactly.

Comment: Not related to the question, about the "parser" disclaimer, did you have a look at abaplint, written in TypeScript ?

Comment: Our tool, smartTool, is under development for 10+ years and allows us (smartShift) to help major SAP customers in their legacy transformation projects. There are some similarities with abaplint but we are talking different ballparks here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addendum February 23rd, the right answer is given by Florian in the comments : "I reported the bug to the docu team and they answered that it has already been reported and they corrected it in the latest version. The new statement is: "**With the second variant without round brackets, chained method calls are not possible and the operators NEW and CAST cannot be used."**"

I let my original answer below (by the way, I think now that in `CALL METHOD static_meth...`, the term "standalone method call" refers to the part "static_meth", so it refers to the two groups of constructs, hence my answer is inexact and the one by SAP is 100% correct)

---

As I can see, the documentation says that the term "standalone method call" refers to these constructs (observe the use of parentheses), which are declared obsolete :

```
CALL METHOD method( ).
CALL METHOD method( 25 ).
CALL METHOD method( a = 1 ).
CALL METHOD method( EXPORTING a = 1 ).
CALL METHOD instance->method( ).
CALL METHOD class=>method( ).
etc.
```

The term ""standalone method call" doesn't refer to these constructs :

```
CALL METHOD method.
CALL METHOD method EXPORTING a = 1.
CALL METHOD instance->method.
CALL METHOD class=>method.
etc.
```

I guess that `CALL METHOD cl->m1( )` belongs to the first group of constructs so **there's an error in the documentation**.

Probably a **not** is missing because it should apply to the second group of constructs (for instance, `CALL METHOD method->method( )` is invalid).

Conclusion by me: you should read "If CALL METHOD is **not** used for the standalone method call, no chained method calls are possible ..."

Conclusion by Florian & SAP: In the comments below, Florian has asked the SAP support and indicates which exact sentence SAP should use in the next official release of the documentation

---

**ADDENDUM** (read it if you think wrongly that the documentation page is about "static methods", I hope I will make it clear that it's not).

The answers in this question prove that the [documentation "CALL METHOD - Static Method Call (Obsolete)"](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_static.htm) is **quite confusing**.

The documentation title: here "static method call" means **"static call of methods"**, not "call of static methods" (while at other places it could possibly have this meaning). If we could add parentheses in the written language, that would give these two possibilities, respectively :

- **static (method call)** : static call of a method (whatever this method is of type "static" or "instance"; we could have a static call of an instance method)
- **(static method) call** : call of a static method

Definitions :

- **static call** : the class, interface or method names are "hardcoded" as symbols in the source code, not text literals, so that they are known by the compiler (for instance, `CALL METHOD class=>method.`). The opposite, a dynamic call, means that the names are passed through variables, which are only known at runtime (for instance, `DATA classvar TYPE seoclsname VALUE 'CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR'. CALL METHOD (classvar)=>(methodvar).`) This other [documentation page](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenmethod_calls.htm) shows well that "static method call" is opposed to "dynamic method call", it **never** talks about "static and instance methods", only about "static method call" and "dynamic method call".
- **static method** : a method being declared with `CLASS-METHODS`. For instance, a static call could be `cl_ixml=>create( )`, and a dynamic call could be `DATA classvar TYPE seoclsname VALUE 'CL_IXML'. CALL METHOD (classvar)=>create`.

Something in the documentation which confused me too, is the use of the term "static method" and examples based on static method only, because in fact the documentation page is about "static call", not static methods (instance methods could have been used) :

- **Syntax** : `CALL METHOD { static_meth( ) | static_meth( a ) | ...` : what does mean "static_meth" here? In fact "static_meth" doesn't mean that it's a static method but it's any method in the context of a **static method call**. If you look at the documentation pages about "[static calls](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_static_short.htm)" and "[dynamic calls](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_dynamic.htm)", you will see that the syntax is respectively `static_meth( ) ...` and `CALL METHOD dynamic_meth ...`
- **Example** : a static method is again used in the three calls, all three of them having the same exact meaning but written with different syntaxes, to demonstrate that the first two calls are obsolete, and only the third one is recommended. In fact all three examples should have better used an instance method to avoid the confusion!

Comment: I don't see any difference betweet 1st and 2nd group. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Suncatcher The first group has parentheses (BTW I didn't know that it was possible, until I read it yesterday).

Comment: Well, my feeling is, too, that there's a problem with the documentation. But it's futile to ponder exacty where. It's owned by SAP and only they have the power - and the duty - to maintain it.

Comment: It is not an error in the documentation. The documentation says about static method calls (defined by `CLASS-METHOD`). The example has an ordinary method that needs a reference to the object to be called.

Comment: @Jagger that what I was confused with. Everybody speaks about static methods whereas in original question there are only usual ones. What's going on, guys :)

Comment: @Suncatcher "everybody", you mean SAP official documentation? I have added a PART 1 to my answer, to explain that the documentation page is **NOT about "static methods" at all**, it's only about static calls of methods. So Ulrich's question is fully valid.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! I reported the bug to the docu team and they answered that it has already been reported and they corrected it in the latest version. The new statement is: "With the second variant without round brackets, chained method calls are not possible and the operators NEW and CAST cannot be used."

Comment: @Florian thanks, nice job !! (all this time spent for the documentation about obsolete statements... :) )

Comment: Well, the written documentation forms part of the contract and is legally binding. They sure take their job seriously. :-)

Comment: @Florian. Thanks for your comment. Could you post it as regular answer, so I can accept it? Besides that: could you leak a deep link to the docu team you mention? Once in a while I might have some fun for them

Comment: @UlrichScholz maybe my explanation was obscure, but the SAP team just confirmed what I said... Of course if SAP described better than I did, then fine...

Comment: @UlrichScholz, Sandra's answer is correct - though a bit lengthy ;-) - it should be the accepted one. Getting in touch with the docu team is very easy: open the article in the SAP Language Help _in your SAP system_, then in the top right, press the link "Feedback". It creates an e-mail that you can now fill in with your issue. They usually respond swiftly and get in touch with you via e-mail. Note that the published web version of the docu (help.sap.com) doesn't include that link.

Comment: I have just reorganized the answer so that to make it look less confusing (in fact, it looks more like its first version + additions now at the end)

Comment: So, dynamic method calling is impossible without `CALL METHOD`?

Comment: @Suncatcher hopefully dynamic method call has only one meaning (dynamic "method call", i.e. there's no "dynamic method"), so yes the only possibility is with CALL METHOD. And a static "method call" (not a "static method" call) should be done without CALL METHOD as this variant is said obsolete, so now use instance->method( ... ) or class=>method( ... )

Comment: @Florian could you convert your comment into an answer so that I and others can vote for it? (in fact my answer is close but inexact) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the method `m1` is not static in your example and the quotation from the documentation has it that it is about a static method (`CLASS-METHOD`).

The only possible thing might be like in this example.

```
REPORT zutest3.

CLASS class_parent DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS m1 RETURNING VALUE(r) TYPE REF TO class_parent.
    CLASS-METHODS m1_static RETURNING VALUE(r) TYPE REF TO class_parent.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS class_parent IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD m1.
    CREATE OBJECT r.
    WRITE / 'm1'.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD m1_static.
    CREATE OBJECT r.
    WRITE / 'm2'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
* this seems to be possible but no one sane calls a static method on an object reference
  CALL METHOD class_parent=>m1_static( )->m1_static( ).
* the following two are not possible and will not compile either
*  CALL METHOD class_parent=>m1_static( )=>m1_static( ).
*  class_parent=>m1_static( )=>m1_static( ).
```

Second of all the `CALL METHOD` statement in this case is just a redundancy and its role is only informative.

Those two are equivalents

```
CALL METHOD cl->m1( ).
cl->m1( ).
```

analogically to for example this

```
DATA i TYPE i.
COMPUTE i = i + 1.
i = i + 1.
```

Comment: Jagger, thanks for your answer. Several things here. First, SAP ABAP uses "static" in two meanings w.r.t. method calls. You read it in the sense of non-instance access, i.e., accessing a static class component. While I'm not 100% sure, I guess, the intended meaning is non-dynamic, as the other, non-obsolete variant of CALL method that the documentation gives is that of CALL METHOD dynamic_meth.  Then, to me class_parent=>m1_static( )->m1_static( ) would qualify as  method chaining. Not sure.  Finally, "no one sane". Come on, it's ABAP :-)

Comment: I agree with @ulrichscholz, the documentation page is not about **static methods**, it's about **static call of methods**. I have extended my answer to demonstrate it (was not easy and took me some time!)

Comment: @SandraRossi And what would this mythical **static call of method** be? There is no such thing. Just look at the examples in the documentation. They all have `CLASS-METHODS`.

Comment: @Jagger I have explained all in details in the PART 1 of my answer, with links to "static call" in the ABAP documentation, and explanation for the examples too.

Answer (score 0):

A bug in the docu. I reported it to the docu team and they answered that it has already been reported and they corrected it in the latest version.

The new statement is:

> With the second variant without round brackets, chained method calls
>   are not possible and the operators NEW and CAST cannot be used.